# Colors dont load on outlook

Tags: outlook

Im creating an email sender that in an email displays a table with data color coded acording to the department it belongs too but several colors dont get shown and it repicks magenta and yellow where light coral and blue should be

```
//through Console.writeline i made sure that data is picked correctly 
 private string getColor(string color)
    {
        string colour="";

        if (color.Equals("Red"))
        {
            colour = "#FFF08080";
        }
        if (color.Equals("Blue"))
        {
            colour = "#FFADD8E6";
        }
        if (color.Equals("Yellow"))
        {
            colour = "#FFFFFF00";
        }
        if (color.Equals("Orange"))
        {
            colour = "#FFFFA500";
        }
        if (color.Equals("Green"))
        {
            colour = "#FF90EE90";
        }

        return colour;
```

im almost sure it has to do with outlook but i havent been able to get a color te get properly displayed and is actualy visible

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem, there are certain hexadecimals that outlook doesnt catch and it substitute them with others already selected, its just a matter of trying hexadecimals until it works, i would apreciate if someone found/made a list of colors that work on outlook365